# Detect player in square radius relative to command block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

the command i am using right now is this one:

```
/execute positioned ~ ~7 ~ run execute if entity @a[team=Player01,distance=..5]
```

the problem is that the área is not a square, so it does not detect the player in the corners of a 5 blocks radius square.
i tried this to fix the problem:

```
/execute positioned ~ ~7 ~ run execute if entity @a[team=Player01,dx=5,dy=5,dz=5]
```

but it somehow does only detect the player in 1/4 of the square
please help

Comment: What exactly is the area you want to check? If you want for example a 10×10×10 cube centered on the command block, you need something like `/execute positioned ~-5 ~-5 ~-5 run say @a[dx=10,dy=10,dz=10]`.

Comment: theres in the circuit i build 4 command blocks with this command , each in a position but all in the same Z position, i need all of them to check a  9x9x9 cube that has exacly a 5 block radius starting 4 blocks above the command block

Comment: Then just change the coordinates accordingly. What is your question?

Comment: i never used square radius before so i have no clue on how it Works except with specific coordinates like x=1 dx=2 y=1 dy=2...

Comment: like, the frist 3 coordinates i wrote at "/execute positioned ..." are one of the corners and the ones inside the brackets are the other coordinates ?

Comment: Did you look at the wiki?

Comment: i tried to use the wiki but i found it too confusing to find exaclty what i was searching for